# Reconciling electron configuration and valence electron distribution over separate energy levels in energy band theory

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

This seemed like more of a chemistry question to me, but I was told by the people at chemistry.stackexchange that it might be more appropriate to post here, since "it was the physics guys that did all of this".

---

The electron configuration of a Silicon atom in its ground state is $1s^2 2s^2 2p^2 3s^2 3p^2$, or equivalently, $[Ne] 3s^2 3p^2$.

When looking at the energy-level scheme of a silicon atom, the valence electrons are distributed over two separate energy levels; specifically, the $3s$ and $3p$ energy levels. It is then said that, as you bring multiple Silicon atoms closer together, the two energy levels will split and overlap. And because the two energy levels are splitting and overlapping, they will produce two energy bands separated by a region of energy that is not allowed. Of these two energy bands, the lower energy band is referred to as the **valence band**, and the higher energy band is referred to as the **conduction band**.

I am familiar with the phenomena of valence and conduction bands, as well as the "region of energy that is not allowed", otherwise commonly referred to as the "forbidden energy gap".

However, I'm wondering what this phenomenon of the valence electrons being distributed over two separate energy levels is? How does one reconcile this with the electron configuration $1s^2 2s^2 2p^2 3s^2 3p^2$, which seems to suggest that the electrons remain in discrete, well-defined energy levels (rather than overlapping)?

I would appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

---

Just to add some clarification, in case some people don't understand the question:

I'm essentially asking for an explanation of how valence electrons can be "distributed" over many separate energy levels, rather than being contained in a single energy level at a time. The latter is what seems to be suggested by the "electron configuration" that we are taught in basic chemistry, but the former is what we are taught in solid-state/semiconductor physics.

Comment: I found the answer to my question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22354/why-do-molecular-orbitals-in-solids-merge-to-bands).